# what is different at same libc? 1.2 1.3 1.4 etc

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, glibc, libc

Reference: https://libc.nullbyte.cat/
There are same libc-2.27.so but different Ubuntu.
Ex)

- libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64
- libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.3_amd64
- libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64

What these number means? 1.2 1.3 1.4?

How can i check Ubuntu version corresponding libc?

Answer (score 1):

> What these number means? 1.2 1.3 1.4?

It means Ubuntu (the distributor) took GLIBC-2.27 upstream source and built a binary package from that source.

Then they tested this package, discovered some bugs which affect them, modified their source to apply fixes, and rebuilt the package. Rinse and repeat.

To find out what's different between these packages, use `zless /usr/share/doc/libc6/changelog.Debian.gz`.